# android leaves application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exit-code

Im creating an application that has audio. I managed to do the audio. Then I realize that when I exit the application using either the back and home button, the audio wont stop. Therefore Im trying to insert 2 different kinds of code. Firstly

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        mp.stop();
       this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Secondly:

```
    @Override       
    protected void onStop() 
    {
        super.onStop();
        // This above line closes the app correctly
       android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

But both unfortunately all these codes make my app crash when I clicked on the button. I've checked that my application works fine only without these codes above. Or is there any other way I can set my mediaplayer to stop when android detects the user has exited the application.Please help?

Comment: Never use this method...`android.os.Process.killProcess(...)`

Comment: Oh?? This is my first time doing android.. So I quite unsure to what is the do's and dont's. Found it on some website though.. Thought it would help.. But it didnt. Even if I swapped the android.os... with mp.Stop(); It still crashes. Thanks for the reminder anyways~

Comment: The safe way to end an `Activity` is to simply use `finish()` - let the Android OS handle everything else. Using `finish()` is a bit like using the Shutdown / Standby / Hibernate options on your computer - it does it without risking loss of data. Using `killProcess(...)` is a bit like ripping the power lead out of the back of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in onStop() method just before you call stop() on mediaPlayer use isPlaying() method to check if it's currently playing or check mp against the null.

```
    @Override       
    protected void onStop() 
    {
         super.onStop();

         if (mp.isPLaying()) {
              mp.reset();
          mp.release();
          mp = null;
     }   
    }
```

That will stop your mediaPlayer.

Comment: Try to check against the null if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()). If still crashes please post your log cat becasue that might be a different reason of the crash

Comment: After looking through my codes.. and is guessing that maybe my splash page is the problem.. Does creating a splash page affects certain codes?? Because before inserting the splash page, I actually tried those codes and it worked perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0):

Just terminate the activity using `finish()`. It will stop all the processes associated with the activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
       this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

If the problem is still there, then you might need to post your logcat.

Comment: My app didnt crash.. But the code dosent work at all in my application. My audio was still playing when i press the home button and when my app exited.

Answer (score 0):

If stopping the audio is what you want then just call [`MediaPlayer#stop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop%28%29) or [`MediaPlayer#release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29) in onStop of the activity.

Answer (score -1):

The way I did it is but starting a timer on the on Pause method. I set the timer to 0.5 sec or something similar. If the on resume method is called before the timer expires then I cancel it (this means we are going from an activity to an activity) 
If the timer expires then I stop the music. This means the activity is at home 
Hope this helps. Not the cleanest solution but i found it to be the least work and no new permissions required

Comment: Why the downvote?! It works and it was suggested once in a while on SO (but I can't find it so I couldnt reference it)